# BizTalk MessageBox > 60GB

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk 2010 Server up and running for a few months.
Recently we noticed that the MessageBox grows and throttling kicked in.

In production, the MessageBox is > 60 GB and the trackingdata view returns 1.5m records.
In our acceptance environment, the trackingdata view returns about 300k records.

We missed to create a dedicated tracking host in the first place, but managed to create one in acceptance last week. The dedicated tracking host has not changed anything in our acceptance environment, therefore I have not yet created one in production.

All jobs are enabled and run continuously without an error.
In acceptance, I do not have any running/suspended messages.
I also can't find any exceptions in the event log.

I'm looking forward to any hint to improve the setup and reduce the messagebox size.

Thanks & best regards
Michael

Comment: Did you run the **Biztalk MsgBoxViewer**? What does it suggest?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is one of the things you've mentioned - i.e.  TrackedMessages copy / purge job, or the MessageBox cleanup jobs, or that you have a large number of running or suspended messages. Is your tracking database getting updated?

Comment: @user1826905: I have the following critical warnings:
- Total DB Space Used for MsgBox Db
- BizTalkJob Monitor BizTalk Server  failed (1 Msg with RefCount < 0)
- Long time waiting SPID(s) detected on SQL Server XXX

Comment: @StuartLC: if i query the tracking database using the view (select count(*) from biztalkdtadb.dbo.trackingdata), I get 0 records...

Comment: A totally unrelated issue could also be the cause for other jobs not to perform properly. Its the Max Job History. Check [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkcpr/archive/2008/05/08/blocking-on-sql-can-occur-if-the-maximum-job-history-log-size-is-greater-than-1000-on-the-sql-server-agent.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkcpr/archive/2008/05/08/blocking-on-sql-can-occur-if-the-maximum-job-history-log-size-is-greater-than-1000-on-the-sql-server-agent.aspx). We too had a similar issue and this solved it.

Comment: @MFox and this `select count(*) from [BizTalkDTADb].[dbo].[Tracking_Parts1]` or just `sp_spaceused` ?

Comment: @StuartLC Tracking_parts1 has 0 records, but sp_spaceused returns a database size of about 8gb (1gb unallocated)

Comment: @user1826905 thanks for the link, I checked this and it's not an issue in my case

Comment: I finally managed to create a dedicated tracking host, but there is no improvement after a few days with this setup. when there is no traffic in biztalk, the trackingdata (trackingdata_1_*) goes down 30 records in about 10 minutes, not really fast enough...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see the sql server jobs that purge records from the database are running?

Look at the sql server agent job named 'MessageBox_Message_Cleanup_BizTalkMsgBoxDb' (there are others there as well). They normally run periodically to clean things up. You might run the job manually and see if there are errors and check the job activity monitor.